# Pulling and committing with Rstudio and github on a windows subsystem for linux

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rstudio

I have a windows 10 running an ubuntu subsystem and for a stats class/coding course (I am a bioinformatics student) we will be doign a term long group project using Rstudio and collaborating via github to teach us how to do follow a proper collaborative development workflow.  My question is if it's possible to run the Rstudio terminal in the ubuntu subsystem so that I can work in that subsystem and commit and pull to github in a the linux environment?  I think this would be easier and would avoid path issues for relative directories.

Please let me know any issues I may not be aware of or if I should just stick to using windows in Rstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you need only `R` session for such operations.

See https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/master/_build.sh and https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/master/_deploy.sh for details.

Comment: I'm beginning to see that now